# Using bluetooth create_bond_out_of_band()

Tags: android, java-native-interface, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I need to force an Android phone to use oob data for pairing. That means I want the Android phone to have the "OOB Data Flag" being set, when the phone sends a Pairing Request to a device.

What I've tried so far: I've identified platform/system/bt to be the current (6.0.1) Android Bluetooth implementation and platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth being a Java wrapper around BT.

platform/system/bt exposes it's interface through a `bt_interface_t` structure. That structure contains a function named `create_bond_out_of_band`that should do what I need. Unfortunately, that function is not exposed by the Java Wrapper.

First I've tried to use the JNI function `const bt_interface_t* android::getBluetoothInterface()` from `libbluetooth_jni.so`. I managed to lookup that function during runtime, but when I call it, it returns 0. At that point, the app used already a lot of the bluetooth API.

This led me to the conclusion, that either, the shared object was loaded a second time, or that the bluetooth library is not part of my application, but somehow implemented in a different process.

Second, I've tried to use the Android `libhardware` API. I've managed to get the BT module, a BT device and finally call the create_bond_out_of_band() from the `bt_interface_t`. The function returns 0, which indicates success, but no Pairing Request is send out. I see following messages in the logs:

```
02-02 15:24:38.083 5791-5824/? E/bt_btif: btif_hh_virtual_unplug: Error, device C4:BE:84:BA:DA:0B not opened.
02-02 15:24:38.083 5791-5791/? E/Gatt: createBondOutOfBand: create_bond_out_of_band(0)
02-02 15:24:38.086 490-2881/? D/audio_hw_primary: out_set_parameters: enter: usecase(1: low-latency-playback) kvpairs: routing=2
02-02 15:24:38.101 490-2881/? D/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: out_snd_device(2: speaker) in_snd_device(0: none)
02-02 15:24:38.101 490-2881/? D/msm8974_platform: platform_send_audio_calibration: sending audio calibration for snd_device(2) acdb_id(101)
02-02 15:24:38.101 490-2881/? I/soundtrigger: audio_extn_sound_trigger_update_device_status: device 0x2 of type 0 for Event 1
02-02 15:24:38.108 490-2881/? D/msm8974_platform: platform_send_audio_calibration: sending audio calibration for snd_device(69) acdb_id(102)
02-02 15:24:38.108 490-2881/? D/audio_hw_primary: enable_snd_device: snd_device(69: vi-feedback)
02-02 15:24:38.108 490-2881/? D/audio_hw_primary: enable_audio_route: apply and update mixer path: spkr-vi-record
02-02 15:24:38.132 490-2881/? D/msm8974_platform: platform_send_audio_calibration: sending audio calibration for snd_device(27) acdb_id(4)
02-02 15:24:38.132 490-2881/? I/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB AFE returned = -19
02-02 15:24:38.133 490-2881/? D/audio_hw_primary: enable_audio_route: apply and update mixer path: low-latency-playback
02-02 15:24:38.672 490-2881/? D/audio_hw_primary: disable_audio_route: reset and update mixer path: low-latency-playback
02-02 15:24:38.674 490-2881/? D/audio_hw_primary: disable_snd_device: snd_device(2: speaker)
02-02 15:24:38.690 600-600/? E/QCALOG: [MessageQ] ProcessNewMessage: [LOWI-SERVER] unknown deliver target [OS-Agent]
02-02 15:24:38.693 490-2881/? D/audio_hw_primary: disable_snd_device: snd_device(69: vi-feedback)
02-02 15:24:38.693 490-2881/? D/audio_hw_primary: disable_audio_route: reset and update mixer path: spkr-vi-record
02-02 15:24:38.696 490-2881/? I/soundtrigger: audio_extn_sound_trigger_update_device_status: device 0x2 of type 0 for Event 0
```

`C4:BE:84:BA:DA:0B` is the device, I try to pair with.

Any ideas? How I can archive my goal or at least some pointers to where an active Android community can be found?

Thanks in advance,
Torsten